# How to pass list of addresses or another function as bytes in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

In Uniswap smart contract there's this method:

```
function uniswapV2Call(address sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, bytes calldata data)
```

I'd like to call it an pass addresses as data or another function.

```
function uniswapV2Call('0x233', 1, 0, ['0x33','0x44'])
```

or

```
function uniswapV2Call('0x233', 1, 0, anotherfunction)
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On-chain call from another contract**

You can use `abi.encode` and `abi.encodePacked` to [encode](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html) the data to `bytes`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    function uniswapV2Call(address sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, bytes calldata data) external {
    }
    
    function passArray() external {
        bytes memory data = abi.encode([
            address(0x33),
            address(0x44)
        ]);
        this.uniswapV2Call(address(0x233), 1, 0, data);
    }
    
    function passFuncionCall() external {
        bytes memory data = abi.encodePacked(
            bytes4(keccak256('anotherfunction(uint256,address)')), // function signature
            abi.encode(
                123, // `anotherfunction()` arguments
                address(0x45)
            )
        );
        this.uniswapV2Call(address(0x233), 1, 0, data);
    }
}
```

`abi.encode` leaves the leading/trailing (depending on the datatype) zeros of each argument, while `abi.encodePacked` trims them.

So the combination of `encodePacked` and `encode` in the `passFunctionCall` example returns

```
0x
58de5f3c // function signature
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b // 1st argument
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045 // 2nd argument
```

If you only `encode`d all params, it would leave the trailing zeros for the `bytes4` type, which you don't want in this case, because the recipient would read (hex)"64 zeros" instead of (hex)"7b" as the first argument, the other argument would be incorrect as well, and the (hex)"45" would be ignored.

```
0x
58de5f3c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045

// same data, just differently formatted for readability

0x
58de5f3c // function signature
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // 1st argument
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b00000000 // 2nd argument
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045 // ignored
```

---

**Off-chain generate the `bytes` argument.**

You can use [web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-abi.html#encodeparameter) for example to encode the address array

```
const data = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('address[2]', ['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000033','0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000044']);
```

returns

```
0x
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044
```

Or you can use the [encodeFunctionCall()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall) to get `bytes` for the function call.

```
const data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    name: 'anotherfunction',
    type: 'function',
    inputs: [{
        type: 'uint256',
        name: ''
    },{
        type: 'address',
        name: ''
    }]
}, ['123', '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000045']);
```

returns

```
0x
58de5f3c // function signature
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b // 1st argument
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045 // 2nd argument
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect and complete answer!